# Working on UIPagerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I am working on `UIPagerViewController` So I didn't find any method when I select any page or tapped on any Page.

So if anybody knows please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Page view controllers manage other view controllers, which can do whatever they want with user taps and other gestures. The child view controller might have buttons, collection views, table views, sliders, etc. Thus there isn't really a universal way to handle taps on a single page.

You could certainly implement such a thing. Subclass UIPageViewController and have it conform to a protocol that defines a "the user tapped on a page" method. (You might want to trigger this method by attaching a tap gesture recognizer to the view controller's content view.) Then give all the child view controllers that you use to fill the page view controller a delegate property that conforms to that protocol and send a "the user tapped on me" message to the delegate when the user taps on the child view controller.